# why do this defition in textbook return 2 values?

Tags: python, return, why3, introsort

**In this post I will do 3 things in order:**

***A introduce the question***

***B display the answer in the textbook to this question***

***C show my doubt***

---

***A introduce the question***

The question goes like this:

---

(1)
Make a list or tuple containing a series of 10 numbers and five letters.
Randomly select four numbers or letters from the list and print a message saying that any ticket matching these four numbers or letters wins a prize;

(2)
Make a list or tuple containing a series of 10 numbers and five letters.
Randomly select four numbers or letters from the list and print a message saying that any ticket matching these four numbers or letters wins a prize.

---

***B display the answer in the textbook to this question***

This answer code is from the textbook:

```
(1)

from random import choice

possibilities = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

winning_ticket = []
print("Let's see what the winning ticket is...")

# We don't want to repeat winning numbers or letters, so we'll use a
#   while loop.
while len(winning_ticket) < 4:
    pulled_item = choice(possibilities)

    # Only add the pulled item to the winning ticket if it hasn't
    #   already been pulled.
    if pulled_item not in winning_ticket:
        print(f"  We pulled a {pulled_item}!")
        winning_ticket.append(pulled_item)

(2)

from random import choice

def get_winning_ticket(possibilities):
    """Return a winning ticket from a set of possibilities."""
    winning_ticket = []

    # We don't want to repeat winning numbers or letters, so we'll use a
    #   while loop.
    while len(winning_ticket) < 4:
        pulled_item = choice(possibilities)

        # Only add the pulled item to the winning ticket if it hasn't
        #   already been pulled.
        if pulled_item not in winning_ticket:
            winning_ticket.append(pulled_item)

    return winning_ticket


def make_random_ticket(possibilities):
    """Return a random ticket from a set of possibilities."""
    ticket = []
    # We don't want to repeat numbers or letters, so we'll use a while loop.
    while len(ticket) < 4:
        pulled_item = choice(possibilities)

        # Only add the pulled item to the ticket if it hasn't already
        #   been pulled.
        if pulled_item not in ticket:
            ticket.append(pulled_item)

    return ticket

def check_ticket(played_ticket, winning_ticket):
    # Check all elements in the played ticket. If any are not in the 
    #   winning ticket, return False.
    for element in played_ticket:
        if element not in winning_ticket:
            return False

    # We must have a winning ticket!
    return True

possibilities = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
winning_ticket = get_winning_ticket(possibilities)

plays = 0
won = False

# Let's set a max number of tries, in case this takes forever!
max_tries = 1_000_000

while not won:
    new_ticket = make_random_ticket(possibilities)
    won = check_ticket(new_ticket, winning_ticket)
    plays += 1
    if plays >= max_tries:
        break

if won:
    print("We have a winning ticket!")
    print(f"Your ticket: {new_ticket}")
    print(f"Winning ticket: {winning_ticket}")
    print(f"It only took {plays} tries to win!")
else:
    print(f"Tried {plays} times, without pulling a winner. :(")
    print(f"Your ticket: {new_ticket}")
    print(f"Winning ticket: {winning_ticket}")

print(check_ticket(new_ticket, winning_ticket))
```

***C Show my doubt***
And my question lies in this para:

```
plays = 0
won = False

# Let's set a max number of tries, in case this takes forever!
max_tries = 1_000_000

while not won:
    new_ticket = make_random_ticket(possibilities)
    won = check_ticket(new_ticket, winning_ticket)
    plays += 1
    if plays >= max_tries:
        break

if won:
    print("We have a winning ticket!")
    print(f"Your ticket: {new_ticket}")
    print(f"Winning ticket: {winning_ticket}")
    print(f"It only took {plays} tries to win!")
else:
    print(f"Tried {plays} times, without pulling a winner. :(")
    print(f"Your ticket: {new_ticket}")
    print(f"Winning ticket: {winning_ticket}")
```

I wonder why it first define
`won=False`,then in the   `if not won` (why doesn't it say if True?)
it defines `won = check_ticket(new_ticket,winning_ticket)`
which can return False or True,
and at the end says `if won`??? is this mean if False? why doesn't it say so?

***And moreover,I wonder why my code to this question connot work:***

```
from random import choice

possibilities=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','a','b','c','d','e']

def make_winning_ticket(possibilities):
    winning_ticket=[]
    while len(winning_ticket)<4:
        new_number=choice(possibilities)
        if new_number not in winning_ticket:
          winning_ticket.append(new_number)
    return winning_ticket

def make_new_ticket(possibilities):
     new_ticket=[]
     while len(new_ticket)<4:
        new_number=choice(possibilities)
        if new_number not in new_ticket:
          new_ticket.append(new_number)
     return new_ticket

play=0
max_try=100000

def check_ticket(new_ticket,winning_ticket):
    while play<max_try:
        for element in new_ticket:
            if new_ticket not in winning_ticket:
             play+=1
             make_new_ticket(possibilities)
             
    print(play)
 


make_winning_ticket(possibilities)
make_new_ticket(possibilities)
check_ticket(winning_ticket,new_ticket)
```

***Thank you for your patience:)***

Comment: Also, assuming some basic fixes for its syntax, that code is wrong for what is seems to intend to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder why it first define `won=False`, then in the `if not won` (why doesn't it say if True?) it defines `won = check_ticket(new_ticket,winning_ticket)` which can return False or True, and at the end says if won??? is this mean if False? why doesn't it say so?

No. It means what it says:

- First we have a while loop which continuously checks whether "we" have won. This decision (won or not won) is saved in a variable `won`.
- In order to be able to properly enter the while loop, the condition (`not won`) must be true, so `won` must be False. So it is set this way.
- After the while loop, we check hether we have won. And it clearly says so: `if won:` means "if we have won".

> And moreover,I wonder why my code to this question connot work:

To be honest, I didn't try to follow each line of it, but what seems to be one of the biggest problems: you discard the return values of your functions.

If we have a function, say

```
def f(x):
    y = 2 * x
    return y
```

it is not sufficient to do

```
f(10)
```

and then to expect that we have done something useful: the `y` variable is completely inside the function. In order to get access to its value, we must do

```
y = f(10) # y will be 20
```

or even (with a completely different name than inside the function):

```
y1 = f(10) # y1 will be 20
y2 = f(15) # y2 will be 30
```

So in your example, you should do at least

```
winning_ticket = make_winning_ticket(possibilities)
new_ticket = make_new_ticket(possibilities)
check_ticket(winning_ticket, new_ticket)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!! I've read your answer and Gained the confidence to try again:D Your example is esay to follow. Really good teacher.

Comment: ```winning_ticket = make_winning_ticket(possibilities)
new_ticket = make_new_ticket(possibilities)
check_ticket(winning_ticket, new_ticket)```     But this code works. Just a reminder.